# Toggle Boolean like toggling classlist Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, boolean, toggle

This is in my data:

```
diceRoll: [{value: null, locked: false,},{value: null, locked: false},{value: null, locked: false}, 
{value: null, locked: false},{value: null, locked: false}],
```

And want to toggle each time an element (dice) is clicked to locked: true or false.

```
<button class="dice textHover" v-for="(roll, index) in diceRoll" v-html="cssDice[roll.value]"   
@click="roll.locked = true, $event.target.classList.toggle('active')" :key="index"></button>
```

Can I toggle the locked boolean that is in my data the same as the `classList`?

I tried: `$event.target.object.toggle('locked')` and some similar ways. But it does not work, also it would be two `@click` events so I might output it in a wrong format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing your logic right inside of your `@click` you should do it in a `method`.

In your `methods` add a new method like this:

```
methods: {
  diceButtonClick(index, $event) {
    this.diceRoll[index].locked = true;
    $event.target.classList.toggle('active');
  }
}
```

Then your button would just be:

```
<button 
   class="dice textHover" 
   v-for="(roll, index) in diceRoll" 
   v-html="cssDice[roll.value]"   
   @click="diceButtonClick(index, $event)" // This is the change
   :key="index">
</button>
```

Comment: I did not try this , but I added it as accepted answer since that works also. It just turns out that if I do this: @click="roll.locked = !roll.locked , it will toggle if I click it again to true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but if I understand you correctly you can use conditional class:

```
:class=“{active: roll.locked}”
```

You can read more about it in [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

Comment: Thanks and apologies for not being clear. I just added an comment with the solution:

It just turns out that if I do this: @click="roll.locked = !roll.locked , it will toggle if I click it again to true or false.